# Source for Identification of Balmer Hydrogen Absorption Lines

Tags: spectroscopy, spectra

I'm working on an assignment, where I have to classify stars using the raw data of the telescope. I'm now trying to calibrate the pixel to armstrong ratio, and for that I need to identify the absorption lines present on the star.

I've been researching for two days now, and I haven't been able to find a 'trustworthy' source of information/confirmation on where to set the Balmer absorption lines for a star like the one in the image (I'm positive H alpha (the one at the far right), beta (on top) and gamma (i would say the one at the left of H beta) are quite prominent).

[image: A spectral profile of 01_HIP105140_3s]

So far, I am trusting on [this page](http://www.fieldtestedsystems.com/starspectra/) to do it. Is there a real source of info, be it a book, an institutional webpage or something, where I can confirm and that I could reference for an assignment? Am I wrong on the position of the Balmer Series?

Comment: Looks like you want to search for the keyword 'line list'. Line lists are datasets generated in our Earthly laboratories for atoms and molecules and under conditions that we might find in space. They usually do the job of line identification in spectra. One that comes to my mind is the MOLAT, but I'm not sure with Temperatures and Pressures those are generated in. Obviously you need a line list for T and P according to a stellar atmosphere.

Comment: Are you claiming that you cannot find the wavelengths of the Balmer lines? Try googling "Balmer lines".

Comment: Try https://sites.google.com/site/rachelfreedastronomy/astronomy-class/spectroscopy